# how to get all jndi bindings in the webSphere

Tags: ejb, websphere, jndi

I have a websphere instance with some ejb's deployed.

How can i find out all the existing JNDI bindings available as part of the websphere instance.

I'm basically validating a feature in our product which gets all the JNDI names available. I'm trying to write the code for implementing the same for my understanding instead of debugging it.

If there is an option in webSphere to get the same that will also suffice for my requirement but I will personally want to write code and try it out.

Comment: If you ask a question on SO you are much more likely to get some good help if you try something first and when (and if) you run into problems you can ask a question about that here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSphere provides the `dumpNamespace` utility for that. Look at `WAS_HOME/bin`, you should find it there.